# Align "span text" with "h3 text" in a row HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a responsive text that has animation. The problem that I am having is my text which suppose to show as below:

[image]

is now appearing like below:

[image]

How shall I make the "Beautiful Colour" text to appear in the same line with the "With a" text, as the above image? Your help is much appreciated as I am still a beginner in HTML CSS and JAVASCRIPT. Thank you.

```js
// Js code to make color box enable or disable
let colorIcons = document.querySelector(".color-icon"),
icons = document.querySelector(".color-icon .icons");

icons.addEventListener("click" , ()=>{
  colorIcons.classList.toggle("open");
})

// getting all .btn elements
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

for (var button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{ //adding click event to each button
    let target = e.target;

    let open = document.querySelector(".open");
    if(open) open.classList.remove("open");

    document.querySelector(".active").classList.remove("active");
    target.classList.add("active");

    // js code to switch colors (also day night mode)
    let root = document.querySelector(":root");
    let dataColor = target.getAttribute("data-color"); //getting data-color values of clicked button
    let color = dataColor.split(" "); //splitting each color from space and make them array

    //passing particular value to a particular root variable
    root.style.setProperty("--white", color[0]);
    root.style.setProperty("--black", color[1]);
    root.style.setProperty("--nav-main", color[2]);
    root.style.setProperty("--switchers-main", color[3]);
    root.style.setProperty("--light-bg", color[4]);

    let iconName = target.className.split(" ")[2]; //getting the class name of icon

    let coloText = document.querySelector(".home-content span");

    if(target.classList.contains("fa-moon")){ //if icon name is moon
      target.classList.replace(iconName, "fa-sun") //replace it with the sun
      colorIcons.style.display = "none";
      coloText.classList.add("darkMode");
    }else if (target.classList.contains("fa-sun")) { //if icon name is sun
      target.classList.replace("fa-sun", "fa-moon"); //replace it with the sun
      colorIcons.style.display = "block";
      coloText.classList.remove("darkMode");
      document.querySelector(".btn.blue").click();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

:root{
  --white: #fff;
  --black: #24292d;
  --nav-main: #4070f4;
  --switchers-main: #0b3cc1;
  --light-bg: #F0F8FF;
}


/* ------------------------this is for navbar section--------------------------------*/

nav{
  position: fixed;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--nav-main);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

nav .navbar{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 1300px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav .navbar a{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--white);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .nav-links{
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .nav-links li{
  margin: 0 8px;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar .nav-links a{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar .nav-links a:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}

.navbar .appearance{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

/* ----------------this is web page appearance in color, icons and so on----------------------*/

.appearance .light-dark,
.appearance .icons{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: var(--white);
  font-size: 20px;
  background: var(--switchers-main);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.appearance .light-dark i,
.appearance .icons i{
  opacity: 1;
}

.appearance .light-dark:hover i,
.appearance .icons:hover i{
  opacity: 1;
}

.appearance .light-dark:hover{
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
}

.appearance .light-dark i{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.appearance .color-icon{
  position: relative;
}

.appearance .icons{
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 14px;
}

.appearance .color-box{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -133px;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: var(--white);
  padding: 16px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.color-box::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  right: 20px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--white);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.color-icon.open .color-box{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.color-icon.open .arrow{
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.appearance .color-box h3{
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  display: block;
  color: var(--nav-main);
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.appearance .color-box .color-switchers{
  display: flex;
}
.color-box .color-switchers .btn{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4070F4;

}
.color-switchers .btn.blue.active{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
              0 0 0 4px #4070F4;
}
.color-switchers .btn.orange{
  background: #F79F1F;
}
.color-switchers .btn.orange.active{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
              0 0 0 4px #F79F1F;
}
.color-switchers .btn.purple{
  background: #8e44ad;
}
.color-switchers .btn.purple.active{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
              0 0 0 4px #8e44Ad;
}
.color-switchers .btn.green{
  background: #3A9943;
}
.color-switchers .btn.green.active{
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff,
              0 0 0 4px #3A9943;
}


/*---------------------this is under home section-----------------------*/

.home-content{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--light-bg);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 60px;
}

.home-content h2{
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 50px;
}

.home-content h3{
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.home-content span{
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 42px;
}

.home-content .text2{

  display: flex;
 }



.home-content h3 span{
  color: var(--nav-main);
}

.home-content h3 span.darkMode{
  color: var(--black);
}

.home-content p{
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 4px 0 30px 0;
}

.home-content a{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px 24px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: var(--nav-main);
}

.home-content a i{
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.home-content a:hover{
  background: var(--switchers-main);
}

@media (max-width: 1050px) {
  .home-content p{
    width: 70%;
  }
}

.home-content .typing-text{
  margin-left: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 4px solid #1de2d1;
  animation: typing 5s steps(15) infinite;
}
@keyframes typing{
  0%{
    width: 0ch;
  }
  50%{
    width: 15ch;
  }
  100%{
    width: 0ch;
  }
}
.home-content .job .one{
  color: #1de2d1;
}
.home-content .job .two{
  color: #1de2d1;
}





.home-content .container{
  width: 246px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.home-content .container .text{
  position: relative;
  color: #4070F4;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.home-content .container .text.first-text{
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.home-content .text.sec-text:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 2px solid #4070F4;
  animation: animate 4s steps(12) infinite;
}
@keyframes animate{
  40%, 60%{
      left: calc(100% + 4px);
  }
  100%{
      left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title> My Website </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <!-- Fontawesome CDN Link -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>

  <body>
      <nav>
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="logo"><a href="#">My Web</a></div>
          
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>

          <div class="appearance">
            <div class="light-dark">
              <i class="btn fas fa-moon" data-color="#e4e6eb #e4e6eb #24292D #24292D #242526"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="color-icon">
              <div class="icons">
                <i class="fas fa-palette"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-sort-down arrow"></i>
              </div>

              <div class="color-box">
                <h3>Color Switcher</h3>
                <div class="color-switchers">
                  <button class="btn blue active" data-color="#fff #24292d #4070f4 #0b3cc1 #F0F8FF"></button>
                  <button class="btn orange"      data-color="#fff #242526 #F79F1F #DD8808 #fef5e6"></button>
                  <button class="btn purple"      data-color="#fff #242526 #8e44ad #783993 #eadaf1"></button>
                  <button class="btn green"       data-color="#fff #242526 #3A9943 #2A6F31 #DAF1DC"></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <section class="home-content">
        <div class="texts">
          <h2 class="text">Customize Your Website </h2>
          <h3 class="text">With a 
            <div class="typing-text">
              <span  class="one">Beautiful Colours... </span>
            </div>
          </h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sited and ametvel, nobised, minimali! Quibusdam temporibus, placeate reessed veritatis optio aliquam illum debitis at, perspiciatis consequatur iure vel, quae ratione. Praesentium, at.</p>
          
          <div class="button">
            <a href="#">Explore Me
            <i class="fas fa-location-arrow"></i></a>
          </div>
          
        
      </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try changing the element with the class `typing-text` from a `div` to a `span`? `div` have a default display of block, which will put it on a new line

Comment: hi evolutionxbox. i had just try your opinion yet there is no changes on the output. i am sorry but thanks again for your help.

Comment: No true. I tried it in the snippet you provided and the typing-text was next to "with a"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it inline you can give the div element a display of inline-flex and then work from there. I attempted to use inline-block on the span but it massively misaligned most of the elements. If you want the typing text closer, then you can maybe look at off-setting the margin.

```
.typing-text {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Or any display value which does not force the element to be 100% width.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and the information you provided, chaffexd. it was just a line of code that caused me a lot of problems. appreciate your help a lot.